# Tensorflow TFX pipeline in Windows machine is failing when trying to create a folder with Linux like folder naming structure

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

### I am trying to run the simple TFX pipeline in Windows 10 machine. I am using the codes as given in Tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/penguin_simple). While trying to run the pipeline, it is throwing below error. The folder name is using a mix of '\' and '/' while TFX is trying to create the folder. I am not sure, how to solve this issue as it is happening within Tensorflow internal code.

---

### ERROR:absl:Failed to make stateful working dir: pipelines\penguin-simple\CsvExampleGen.system\stateful_working_dir\2021-06-24T20:11:37.715669
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tfx\orchestration\portable\outputs_utils.py", line 211, in get_stateful_working_directory
fileio.makedirs(stateful_working_dir)
File "G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tfx\dsl\io\fileio.py", line 83, in makedirs
_get_filesystem(path).makedirs(path)
File "G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tfx\dsl\io\plugins\tensorflow_gfile.py", line 76, in makedirs
tf.io.gfile.makedirs(path)
File "G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 483, in recursive_create_dir_v2
_pywrap_file_io.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Failed to create a directory: pipelines\penguin-simple\CsvExampleGen.system\stateful_working_dir/2021-06-24T20:11:37.715669; Invalid argument

Comment: Based on https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/950, tfx supports mac and linux currently.
Please try switching to linux based systems.

Comment: Thanks for this guidance; it helped a lot